# How to parse std::string containing unicode literals?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, ascii

I have `std::string` which stores characters encoded in UTF. Example:

```
std::string a = "\\u00c1\\u00c4\\u00d3";
```

Note that the length of `a` is 18 (3 characters, 6 ASCII symbols for each UTF character).

**Question**: How can I convert `a` into C++ string that have only 3 characters? Are there any standard functions (libraries) to do that?

Comment: Please specify which operating system. wstring is different in different systems and some systems have specific functions for this.

Comment: It's [complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019).  You may need [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/design/cpp), or OS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the standard C++ library to handle this kind of conversion automatically for you. You are going to have to parse this string yourself, manually converting each 6-char `"\uXXXX"` substring into a 1-wchar value `0xXXXX` that you can then store into a `std::wstring` or `std::u16string` as needed.

For example:

```cpp
std::string a = "\\u00c1\\u00c4\\u00d3";

std::wstring ws;
ws.reserve(a.size());

for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size();)
{
    char ch = a[i++];

    if ((ch == '\\') && (i < a.size()) && (a[i] == 'u'))
    {
        wchar_t wc = static_cast<wchar_t>(std::stoi(a.substr(++i, 4), nullptr, 16));
        i += 4;
        ws.push_back(wc);
    }
    else
    {
        // depending on the charset used for encoding the string,
        // this may or may not need to be decoded further...
        ws.push_back(static_cast<wchar_t>(ch));
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/qx4LUs)

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::string a = "\\u00c1\\u00c4\\u00d3";
 
std::wstring ws;
ws.reserve(a.size());
 
size_t start = 0;
do
{
    size_t found = a.find("\\u", start);
    if (found == std::string::npos) break;

    if (start < found)
    {
        // depending on the charset used for encoding the string,
        // this may or may not need to be decoded further...
        ws.insert(ws.end(), a.begin()+start, a.begin()+found);
    }
 
    wchar_t wc = static_cast<wchar_t>(std::stoi(a.substr(found+2, 4), nullptr, 16));
    ws.push_back(wc);
 
    start = found + 6;
}
while (true);
 
if (start < a.size())
{
    // depending on the charset used for encoding the string,
    // this may or may not need to be decoded further...
    ws.insert(ws.end(), a.begin()+start, a.end());
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/dJSlFl)

Otherwise, use a 3rd party library that already does this kind of translation for you.